# Android : Firebase authentication via SMS, an error "SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17052 Exceeded quota." responsed

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am currently using Firebase authentication's SMS verification, and I have only been using ten sets of virtual phone numbers for testing. However, I've noticed that after successfully logging in a few dozen times, the next time I request a verification code, it starts responding with 'SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17052 Exceeded quota.' This error response persists for several hours or even a day before it becomes possible to request verification codes successfully again.

It seems that only Android devices within the same Firebase project are experiencing this issue, while iOS devices are not affected.

I have also added SHA1 and SHA256 to the Firebase console.